# Listing top K endpoints by exception count with prometheus

Tags: prometheus, spring-micrometer, prometheus-java

I'm using spring boot 2.x & using micrometer to record inbound http request metrics to PrometheusMeterRegistry.

Spring boot metrics actuator endpoint displayed the metric as below

`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v2/endpoint1",} 272.0`
`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="SomeException",method="GET",status="400",uri="/v2/endpoint1",} 8.0`
`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="SomeOtherException",method="GET",status="422",uri="/v2/endpoint1",} 5.0`
`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="None",method="GET",status="200",uri="/v2/endpoint2",} 472.0`
`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="SomeException",method="GET",status="400",uri="/v2/endpoint2",} 11.0`
`http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="SomeOtherException",method="GET",status="422",uri="/v2/endpoint2",} 7.0`

I'm interested in the below outcome

Output: (top 10 in last x minutes)

```
1, /v2/endpoint2, {actual count of non 200 status codes in last minutes or so}
2, /v2/endpoint1, {actual count of non 200 status codes in last minutes or so}
```

I tried with a count function something similar to below. However it doesn't let me provide the time range. I couldn't get it work the way i mentioned above. Appreciate any help on this.

```
count(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status!="200"}) by (uri, method)
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the total per uri/method, and then select the top 10 of them:

```
topk(10,
  sum by (uri, method)(
    increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{status!="200"}[10m])
  )
)
```